# Как разместить img в рабочей области bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Верстаю макет на bootstrap3. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Мне необходимо разместить изображения в 3 колонки, НО! изображения большого размера (width и height) и они не помещаются в сетке т.к. уже два изображения по факту занимают все 12 колонок.

Вот мой код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
            <div class="left-photo">
                <img src="img/main-picture/picture-left.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="picture-center">
                <img src="img/main-picture/picture-center.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-1 col-md-3">
            <div class="picture-right">
                <img src="img/main-picture/picture-main-right.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: необходимо добавить класс для img  - img-responsive. Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/L1gdLztn/

Comment: СПАСИБО! Всё ок!

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте изображениям класс `img-responsive`. С его помощью Бутстрап задаёт изображениям три свойства:

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Свойство `max-width` не позволит изображениям выходить за края своих колонок.

Получится:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
            <div class="left-photo">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/main-picture/picture-left.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="picture-center">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/main-picture/picture-center.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-1 col-md-3">
            <div class="picture-right">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="img/main-picture/picture-main-right.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО! Всё ок!

Comment: Я с бутсрап ещё не работал. Много по нему вопросов) Не скажите может быть есть какой-то список основных классов бутсрап? на сайте у них ничего такого не нашёл.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp

Comment: Спасибо за азбуку бутстрап)